# y'' -((1+x^2)+a x)/(b(1+x^2)^3))y == 0

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation for $y(x)$:

$$y''(x) -\frac{1+x^2+a x}{b(1+x^2)^3}y(x) = 0,\qquad (a,b\in\mathbb{R})$$

Looking for closed form solutions in terms of special functions.

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Do you have any initial or boundary conditions?

Comment: In addition to the nicely printed equation, always also include Mathematica code for users to copy.

Answer (score 5):

Version 11.3 performs the answer in terms of `DifferentialRoot` (see its help for more info):

```
DSolve[y''[x] - (1 + x^2 + a*x)/b/(1 + x^2)^3*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

> {{y[x]->DifferentialRoot[Function[{[FormalY],[FormalX]},{(-1-[FormalX]^2-[FormalX] a) [FormalY][[FormalX]]+(1+[FormalX]^2)^3 b ([FormalY]^[Prime][Prime])[[FormalX]]==0,[FormalY][0]==C[1],([FormalY]^[Prime])[0]==C[2]}]][x]}}

In fact, so does Maple producing its answer in terms of the so-called HeunD function, but the above answer is better to work with.

Comment: How do I clarify that the DifferentialRoot is the same as a Doubly Confluent Heun function? Any ideas?

Comment: @Bongy: Thank you for your interesting and important request. One may look in https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DESol&term=DESol and https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunD&term=HeunD to this end. I won't go into syntax details.